# Create Shape / Drag and Drop

Tags: event-handling, mouseevent, createjs, easeljs

I'm trying to work with a createjs canvas to add new states (circles) on empty spots of stage on click, but drag existing points on click. I'm assuming the problem is that when I try to remove the stagemousemove event in handleMove it doesn't properly remove since it doesn't have a dedicated static handler, but I'm not sure how I'd even create that handler.

```
// create new state (circle)
function createState(e) {
  x = e.stageX
  y = e.stageY
  if (stage.children.every(el =>
      !(el.hitTest(x, y)) &&
      !(el.hitTest(x + 30, y + 30)) &&
      !(el.hitTest(x + 30, y - 30)) &&
      !(el.hitTest(x - 30, y + 30)) &&
      !(el.hitTest(x - 30, y - 30))
    )) {
    state = new createjs.Shape()
    state.graphics.ss(3)
                  .s('#777')
                  .f('#eaeaea')
                  .dc(x, y, 30)
    stage.addChild(state)
    state.on('mousedown', handleMove)
    stage.update()
  }
}

// drag and drop
function handleMove(e) {
  el = stage.getObjectUnderPoint(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
  var offset = {
    x: el.x - e.stageX,
    y: el.y - e.stageY
  }
   stage.on('stagemousemove', (evt) => {
    el.x = offset.x + evt.stageX
    el.y = offset.y + evt.stageY
    stage.update()
  })
  stage.on('stagemouseup', (e) => {
    stage.off('stagemousemove', (evt) => {
      el.x = offset.x + evt.stageX
      el.y = offset.y + evt.stageY
      stage.update()
    })
  })
}

// determines whether to create new point
function handler(e) {
 if (stage.getObjectUnderPoint(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY) == null)
   createState(e)
}

stage.on('stagemousedown', handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `off()` method, you must pass a *reference* to the `result` of the `on()` call.

```
let listener = stage.on('stagemousemove', (evt) => {
  el.x = offset.x + evt.stageX
  el.y = offset.y + evt.stageY
  stage.update()
});
stage.on('stagemouseup', (e) => {
  stage.off('stagemousemove', listener);
});
```

The `on` method creates a function closure for you automatically to maintain scope, which ES5 JavaScript does not do. This lets you pass a scope parameter to `on` so `this` is the expected scope.

When using arrow functions, this closure happens during ES5 transpiling. You can not just pass a similar function to the `off`, since they are not equal.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Lanny, this works perfect. I had no idea you could get a reference as a return from the `on()` call. There's one problem with the handler though. When I click on an existing state (circle) and drag quickly, it will create a new state in the direction of where I dragged rather than actually dragging the circle.

Comment: It sounds like your `handler()` is firing every time. Note that `stagemousedown` will fire every time, no matter what is clicked. One other thing -- have you looked into the "pressmove" event handler? Does a lot of the management of listeners for drag/drop operations.

Comment: I've look at `'pressmove'` but have trouble calculating the offset for dragging without having two handlers. I understand that `stagemousedown` is fired everytime, but shouldn't my `if` statement not allow for a new state to be created if the click target is a state? It seems there's some delay when clicking and dragging fast. [See a demo here](http://www.greg-wolff.com/fasdemo). Note that if you click and drag on a state quickly, it creates a new state. Logging the mouse target in console.